# How to segregate data in jupyter python 3

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

The question is,"Restricting to the female population, stratify the subjects into age bands no wider than ten years, and construct the distribution of marital status within each age band. Within each age band, present the distribution in terms of proportions that must sum to 1."
The output I want is:

```
                  female
(0,18]        married       123
              not married   123
              divorced      123
(18,20]       married       123
              not married   123
              divorced      123
(20, 30]      married       123
              not married   123
              divorced      123
and so on
```

The code I have so far is:

```
age_distinct = da[["agegrp","RIAGENDRV2","DMDMARTLV2"]].dropna()
#da["agegrp"] = pd.cut(da.RIDAGEYR, [0, 18,20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80])
#da.groupby(["agegrp", "RIAGENDRV2"])["DMDMARTLV2"].value_counts()
(age_distinct.query('RIAGENDRV2 == "Female"'))
#da.groupby(by='RIAGENDRV2').size()
```

The output this gives is:

```
    agegrp  RIAGENDRV2  DMDMARTLV2
3   (50, 60]    Female  Living_With_Partner
4   (40, 50]    Female  Divorced
5   (70, 80]    Female  Separated
7   (30, 40]    Female  Married
12  (20, 30]    Female  Living_With_Partner
13  (60, 70]    Female  Married
15  (50, 60]    Female  Separated
16  (18, 20]    Female  Missing
17  (20, 30]    Female  Never_Married
18  (20, 30]    Female  Never_Married
19  (50, 60]    Female  Divorced
21  (70, 80]    Female  Widowed
22  (60, 70]    Female  Separated
23  (50, 60]    Female  Married
25  (20, 30]    Female  Never_Married
27  (50, 60]    Female  Divorced
29  (60, 70]    Female  Divorced
30  (60, 70]    Female  Married
33  (70, 80]    Female  Married
34  (30, 40]    Female  Married
35  (70, 80]    Female  Married
36  (20, 30]    Female  Married
38  (18, 20]    Female  Never_Married
39  (60, 70]    Female  Married
43  (70, 80]    Female  Widowed
46  (18, 20]    Female  Never_Married
47  (20, 30]    Female  Never_Married
50  (30, 40]    Female  Married
52  (40, 50]    Female  Separated
54  (0, 18] Female  Missing
... ... ... ...
5678    (20, 30]    Female  Never_Married
5679    (20, 30]    Female  Married
5681    (50, 60]    Female  Married
5682    (70, 80]    Female  Divorced
5683    (20, 30]    Female  Never_Married
5684    (60, 70]    Female  Married
5685    (30, 40]    Female  Married
5686    (50, 60]    Female  Living_With_Partner
5689    (40, 50]    Female  Married
5692    (70, 80]    Female  Widowed
5696    (50, 60]    Female  Divorced
5697    (60, 70]    Female  Married
5699    (70, 80]    Female  Divorced
5703    (60, 70]    Female  Married
5704    (70, 80]    Female  Never_Married
5707    (20, 30]    Female  Living_With_Partner
5708    (20, 30]    Female  Married
5710    (70, 80]    Female  Widowed
5712    (20, 30]    Female  Living_With_Partner
5715    (30, 40]    Female  Married
5716    (70, 80]    Female  Widowed
5719    (60, 70]    Female  Married
5721    (30, 40]    Female  Divorced
5722    (30, 40]    Female  Never_Married
5723    (70, 80]    Female  Widowed
5724    (40, 50]    Female  Married
5727    (60, 70]    Female  Married
5730    (70, 80]    Female  Widowed
5732    (70, 80]    Female  Widowed
5734    (20, 30]    Female  Never_Married
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. simulated some sample data that has same characteristics
2. generate an `aggrp` I just went to 20 year buckets
3. only take females, drop the `sex` column going into groupby so it doesn't impact output
4. `count` works fine as aggregate
5. rename an index so "Female" comes out as column header as per your sample output
6. meet requirement by changing counts into percentage that adds up to 1

```
sex = ["Male","Female"]
s = ['Living_With_Partner','Divorced','Separated','Married','Missing','Never_Married','Widowed']
df = pd.DataFrame([[random.randint(15,80), sex[random.randint(0,1)], s[random.randint(0,len(s)-1)]] for r in range(200)],
            columns=["age","sex","status"])

df["agegrp"] = pd.cut(df["age"], pd.interval_range(start=0, end=100, freq=20))
dfa = df[df["sex"]=="Female"].drop("sex",1).groupby(["agegrp","status"]).agg({"age":"count"}).dropna()
dfa.index.names = ['agegrp', 'Female'] # rename column from status to Female as per requirement
dfa = dfa[dfa["age"]>0] # exclude any aggregates where value is zero
dfa.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100* x / (float(x.sum()))).round(2) # change from counts to percentage
```

**output sample**

```
                            age
agegrp  Female  
(0, 20] Divorced            22.22
        Living_With_Partner 5.56
        Married             16.67
        Missing             5.56
        Never_Married       22.22
        Separated           16.67
        Widowed             11.11
```

**even sized bins**

```
b=[]
bs=6
found = False
while not found:
    found = True
    b = sorted([int(round(i.left)) for i in df["age"].value_counts(bins=bs).index] + [df["age"].max()])
    for i in range(1, len(b)-1):
        if b[i]-b[i-1]>10:
            bs += 1
            found = False
            break

df["agegrp"] = pd.cut(df["age"], b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.However i was not able to only show females.

```
    da = pd.read_csv("nhanes_2015_2016.csv")
    da["RIAGENDRV2"]=da.RIAGENDR.replace({1:"Male",2:"Female"})
    da["DMDMARTLV2"]=da.DMDMARTL.replace({1:"Married", 2:"Widowed",3:"Divorced",4:"Separated",5:"Never_Married",6:"Living_with_Partner",77:"Refused",99:"Dont_know"})
```

```
#We create the bins for the age groups and label them

        da["age_group"]=pd.cut(da.RIDAGEYR,bins= [15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85], labels=["15-25","25-35","35-45","45-55","55-65","65-75","75-85"])
```

#Creates a table of the marital status by age group and gender

```
    da.groupby(["age_group","RIAGENDRV2"])["DMDMARTLV2"].value_counts(normalize=True,ascending=False)
```

```
The table will look something like this:

age_group  RIAGENDRV2  DMDMARTLV2         
15-25      Female      Never_Married          0.600733
                       Living_with_Partner    0.197802
                       Married                0.161172
                       Separated              0.029304
                       Divorced               0.010989
           Male        Never_Married          0.734127
                       Living_with_Partner    0.134921
                       Married                0.119048
                       Separated              0.007937
                       Divorced               0.003968
25-35      Female      Married                0.467054
                       Never_Married          0.282946
                       Living_with_Partner    0.184109
                       Divorced               0.044574
                       Separated              0.021318
           Male        Married                0.458244
                       Never_Married          0.286938
                       Living_with_Partner    0.211991
                       Divorced               0.019272
                       Separated              0.017131
                       Widowed                0.006424
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
df["agegrp"] = pd.cut(df["RIDAGEYR"], pd.interval_range(start=10, end=100, freq=10))

women = df[(df["RIAGENDR"] == 2)] #Sorting for Women only

women.groupby(["agegrp","RIAGENDR"])["DMDMARTL"].value_counts(normalize=True,ascending=False)
```

**Answer:**

```
agegrp    RIAGENDR  DMDMARTL 
(10, 20]  2         Nev_mar      0.769231
                    Live_in      0.205128
                    Married      0.025641
(20, 30]  2         Nev_mar      0.445525
                    Married      0.305447
                    Live_in      0.206226
                    Divorced     0.021401
                    Separated    0.021401
(30, 40]  2         Married      0.544304
                    Nev_mar      0.204641
                    Live_in      0.120253
                    Divorced     0.090717
                    Separated    0.035865
                    Widowed      0.004219
```